# Available filesystems for Linux that are case-insensitive?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have a client whose web application was written entirely in a Windows environment and served from windows. Unfortunately there's way to many cases of get `file/At/Somelocation.php` where the file is actually something horrible like `File/at/SomeLocation.PHP`.

I really don't want to be forced to work in Windows, but it will take weeks if not longer to fix all the casing issues. Am I out of luck here?

Edit: 
The casing issues are well known in the project, but since it's only an issue for developers using Linux (me) it's not a big enough priority that needs fixing in the near term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a simple test with a FAT32 USB drive.

Which seems to behave the way you want. What i did:

1. I created a folder called test
2. ls test (works)
3. ls TeSt (works)

Same goes for a file. So if you was to run your files etc on a FAT32 partition it should work. Don't pin me down on this but it'll be worth trying.

Edit: If i were you i would still resort to rectifying his code. Using FAT32 or any other solution is still far from optimal. Oh and you should point this case sensitivity problem out to the original programmer if you can. It's always something to keep in mind when programming.

Comment: i don't see why this wouldn't work, but then you're limited to using FAT32 on any other systems this is deployed on.  probably better to fix the sourcecode once than to have to include a detailed explanation of how to configure Apache or install on a FAT loopback drive.

Comment: The only problem with that is that FAT32 doesn't support access rights.

Comment: yep, using FAT32 within *nix is not really considered as "best practice" and like petersohn said it doesn't support access rights. Like my edit says: Better fix that code than trying to fix things the lazy way :p

Comment: Using FAT32 gets you working and gives you time to fix the issue.

Comment: @mpez0 Exactly my thoughts as well

Comment: About to mark this as the accepted answer because it jogged my memory enough to remember that I can make a filesystem in a file, so with a little bit of command line witchcraft I can make a temporary filesystem just for this project;  skipping out on the virtualization path and saving me immediately 300-500$ in memory and Win 7 licensing costs.